# Validation before Submitting on prompt page

Tags: javascript, cognos

I am trying to use some sort of script on prompt page using HTML Item, what i am trying to accomplish is after clicking finish button script checked if there is nothing left black. Nothing means any of the prompt/filter (text, prompt, date/time) and if it is than it doesn't go through.

Hope i made things clear.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think the fastest and easiest way if you don't already have a js framework is jQuery validate...  check out this page, see the examples and give this a go.  I should think the description you've provided will be covered in the basic usage examples for this plugin.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use jQuery as in Ben's answer, you can use the form's onSubmit event:

```
<form id="datform" action="http://path.to/action.script" onsubmit="return isValidated()">
...
...
'</form>
```

You'll then use a javascript function, ala

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function isValidated(){
    var so=false;
    return so;  
  }
</script>
```

Personally, I prefer jQuery but this allows for some on-the-fly validation

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i am looking into jQuery btw